# Missing sign in Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, momentum, metric-tensor, conventions

This is a triviality, but it's driving me mad not to catch the missing sign.
If the Lagrangian density for the electromagnetic field is

$$
\mathcal{L} = -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{2}(\vec{E}^2 - \vec{B}^2),
$$

in the abscence of electric pontential, $\mathcal{L} = \frac{1}{2}(\dot{\vec{A}}^2 - \vec{B}^2)$. How can the conjugate momentum $$\pi^i = \partial\mathcal{L}/\partial(\partial_0A_i)$$ be

$$
\vec{\pi}=-\dot{\vec{A}} ~?
$$

This last sign is mysterious.

Comment: $A_i=-A^i{}{}$.

Comment: I'm confused here, if I understand your notation $\pi^i = \dot{A}^i$. But then $\pi^i\dot{A}_i = - \dot{A}_i^2=-\vec{E}^2$, however this should be $\pi^i\dot{A}_i = \vec{E}^2$.

Comment: Nope. $\pi^i=\dot A_i=-\dot A^i$.